# How to validate a float input to 2 precision in panel?

Tags: python, scripting, error, panel

I'm trying to validate the inputs in a `FloatProperty` and make sure precision is always up to 2 decimal places. Apparently `precision=2` doesn't cut it as you are still able to input values with 3 precision. but I get an error which doesn't make any sense. I tried these 3 different validate functions and nothing works:

Try 1:

```
def validate_value_input(self, value):
    return round(value, 2) # `ValueError: the return value must be None`
```

Try 2:

```
def validate_value_input(self, value):
    round(value, 2) # is obviously then an unused value
    return None
```

Try 3:

```
def validate_value_input(self, value):
    self.float_input = round(value, 2) # error infinite loop as it recursively validates
```

What gives? How is this supposed to be done?

Here's a sample working script that demonstrates the problem:

```
import bpy

def validate_value_input(self, value):
    return round(value, 2) # ValueError: the return value must be None

class SamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Sample Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_sample_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Sample'

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "float_input")

def register():

    bpy.types.Scene.float_input = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Float Input",
        description="Float Input Description",
        default=0.5,
        min=0,
        max=500,
        precision=2, # you can still input 3 precision values
        set=validate_value_input
    )

    bpy.utils.register_class(SamplePanel)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.float_input
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SamplePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid infinite loop based on method 3

Accroing to API:

update (function) – Function to be called when this value is modified, This function must take 2 values (self, context) and return None. Warning there are no safety checks to avoid **infinite recursion**.

```
import bpy

is_running = [False]

def validate_value_input(self, context):
    if is_running[0]: return

    is_running[0] = True
    self.float_input = int(self.float_input * 100) / 100.0
    is_running[0] = False

class SamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Sample Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_sample_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Sample'

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "float_input")

def register():

    bpy.types.Scene.float_input = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Float Input",
        description="Float Input Description",
        default=0.5,
        min=0,
        max=500,
        precision=5,
        update=validate_value_input
    )

    bpy.utils.register_class(SamplePanel)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.float_input
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SamplePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

##### There is a more accurate version

```
import bpy, decimal

def dec_round(x, n):
    if n < 0:
        fac = 10 ** -n
        x /= fac
        s = "1."
        return float(decimal.Decimal(x).quantize(decimal.Decimal(s), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)) * fac
    else:
        s = "1." + "0" * n
        return float(decimal.Decimal(x).quantize(decimal.Decimal(s), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))

is_running = [False]

def validate_value_input(self, context):
    if is_running[0]: return

    is_running[0] = True
    self.float_input = dec_round(self.float_input, 2)
    is_running[0] = False

class SamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Sample Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_sample_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Sample'

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "float_input")

def register():

    bpy.types.Scene.float_input = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Float Input",
        description="Float Input Description",
        default=0.5,
        min=0,
        max=500,
        precision=5,
        update=validate_value_input
    )

    bpy.utils.register_class(SamplePanel)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.float_input
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SamplePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ah so it indeed looks like a bug. Should I also report this as a bug to Blender since we had to resort to workaround?

Comment: wait I tried this but the value doesn't set in the input. it stays at 0.5

Comment: The new one should work, check it out.

Comment: thanks sooo much! you're a savior!

Comment: FWIW you don't need the `is_running` etc. ordeal, to avoid infinite recursion you can set the property using the dictionary accessor. `self["float_input"] = round(self.float_input, 2)`

Comment: @Gorgious interesting thank you so much for sharing! it works! so there is no bug in blender? this is the proper way to do it? what exactly is an accessor and why does `self["float_input"]` behave differently from `self.float_input`

Comment: You can access custom properties using a lower level dictionary-like structure. This doesn't trigger callback events like update, set, get, etc. It's a quirk of the API and not considered a bug :)